# How do I make it so that the right side of my hollow equilateral triangle prints "\" properly? I have trouble with the spacing

Tags: java

I'm stuck on the third for loop and cannot understand how to make the other side(right side) of the equilateral triangle.

```
public static void printTriangle(int x) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < x; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("/");
        for (int k = i; k > x * 2; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\\");
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int a = 1; a <= x; a++) {
        System.out.print("--");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop

```java
for (int k = i; k > x * 2; k++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Starts at `i`, which is your line index, and goes to `x * 2`, which is double your line count. That means, in the first line you will do the most spacing. You want the exact opposite; In the first line, your edges don't need any spacing, and it should be increasingly more in the next lines:

- First line: Spacing of 0
- Second line: Spacing of 2
- Third line: Spacing of 4
- ... and so on
  So:

```java
for (int k = 0; k < (i - 1) * 2; k++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

should get you what you want.
Output:

```
    /\
   /  \
  /    \
 /      \
/        \
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

The width in char of the triangle at each line is i * 2, so excluding the / and \ characters you have to print i*2 -2 spaces.
Replace

```
for (int k = i; k > x * 2; k++) {
```

with

```
 for (int k = 2; k < i*2; k++) {
```